# Rails: How to escape ampersand in URL formation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a `link_to` helper like the following:

```
<%= link_to "example & text", url_for(:controller =>'example', :title=>"example & text") %>
```

It frames the URL `http://localhost:3000/example?title=example&amp:text`

In the sample controller it calls the `index` method but `params[:title]` returns 
the value `example&amp:text`.

I want to have a value like "example & text". So I have tried 
`CGI::escape()` and `CGI::escapeHTML()` but without luck.

Answer (score 11):

The url needs to be escaped using `CGI.escape`:

```
link_to "example & text", :controller => "example", :title => CGI.escape("example & text")
```

This should generate something like:

```
<a href="/example?title=example+%26+text">example & text</a>
```

Then, wherever you're wanting to use this, you can unescape it again to get it back to normal:

```
CGI.unescape params[:title] # => "example & text"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but still i am getting (amp;) appended after CGI.unescape params[:title] . it returns example &amp; text.

Comment: Also, you could always use `CGI.unescapeHTML` on top of `CGI.unescape`, but that's pretty nasty.

Comment: I am working with Rails 2.3.10...it become heart breaking issue here

Comment: In what context are you needing to use `params[:title]`? If it's in your view, &amp; is what you need anyway.

Comment: Hey , when i use CGI.unescapeHTML(params[:title]) in my example controller it returns "example & text" . smy link_to is your first suggestion. Does this

Comment: Only you can answer whether it solves your problem. It is *a solution*, but whether it's a *good solution* depends on whether you think passing these kind of variables around in urls is a good idea to start with ;)

Answer (score 2):

For this there is a nice rails method  called [raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html).

You can use in this way :

```
<%= link_to raw("example & text"), url_for(:controller =>'example', :title=>raw("example & text")) %>
```

One more this `&` should not be used in the `URL` as it is used as params separator.